# Powershell pass parameter to function to query subproperty of object

Tags: powershell, parameters

I can't find the answer to the following question.

Code:

```
function Get-Sub([string]$select)
{
    $var_string = '{"roles": {"categories": {"test": "111"}}}'
    $psobject = $var_string | ConvertFrom-Json
    $psobject.roles.categories | out-gridview -Title "Working"
    $psobject.$select | out-gridview -Title "Not Working"
}

Get-Sub -select 'roles.categories'
```

How can i get the parameter selection to work?

Comment: You need to resolve each sub-property [one at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69368844/712649)

Comment: GPTChat just gave me the answer:
function Get-Sub([string]$select)
{
    $var_string = '{"roles": {"categories": {"test": "111"}}}'
    $psobject = $var_string | ConvertFrom-Json
    $psobject.roles.categories | Out-GridView -Title "Working"
    
    $result = Invoke-Expression ('$psobject.' + $select)
    if ($result -ne $null) {
        $result | Out-GridView -Title "Now Working"
    } else {
        Write-Error "Property '$select' not found"
    }
}

Get-Sub -select 'roles.categories'